# Passing arguments from function to function in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I'm trying to make a chess game.

Here's the thing I'm trying to make the main menu, and am having trouble. here's the snippit of my code:

```
int mMenu(int&, char&, bool&, char&);

int main(char&) 
{
    int choice;
    char sure;
    bool quit = false;

    char ctrl // used for the control from main menu to main()

    mMenu (choice, sure, quit);

    do
    {
        if (ctrl == a)
            NewGame();
        else if (ctrl == b)
            LoadGame();
        else
            quit = true;
    }
    while (quit == true);

    return 0;
}


int mMenu(int& choice, char& sure, bool& quit, char& ctrl,)
{
    do
{
    cout << "                           Chess                               "
         << "------------------------ Main Menu ------------------------\n"
         << "Please choose what operation you'd like to perform from the         menu below\n\n"
         << "1. New Game.\n"
         << "2. Load Game.\n"
         << "Exit.\n"
         << "Your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "Are you sure you wish to start a new game? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> sure;
        if (sure != 'Y')
            clrscr();
        else
        {
            ctrl = a;
            quit = true;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        ctrl = b;
        quit = true;
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        cout << "Are you sure you wish to exit? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> sure;
        if (sure != 'Y')
            clrscr();
        else
        {
            quit = true;
            ctrl = c;
        }
    }
    }
}
while (quit = true);

return ctrl;
}
```

From that code my compiler (visual c++) is saying that int the main() function, mMenu does not take 3 arguments. What is wrong and how do I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Also as you can see I'm trying to use clrscr(); but the compiler is flagging it saying it cannot find the definition for it, despite putting in the #include  any ideas?

Comment: You've defined a function that takes 4 arguments, but you've only provided 3 parameters when you try to call it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth put it as an answer! :)

Comment: `int mMenu(int& choice, char& sure, bool& quit, char& ctrl = 0)` last parameter with default value

Comment: Note: `int main(char&)` in the global namespace should not compile cleanly for a hosted implementation.

Comment: Note 2: `char ctrl` is missing a semicolon and shouldn't compile.

Comment: Note 3: **if** `while (quit == true);` were correct, then it would be much better expressed as `while (quit);`. However, most likely the correct line is `while( !quit );`. Also, you probably want to have the menu presentation within that loop, not before it.

Comment: Note 4: `while (quit = true);`, with an assignment operator `=` instead of the equality comparison operator `==`, is most certainly wrong.

Comment: Regarding `clrscr`, that is not a standard library function. Check out e.g. [this earlier SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930138/is-clrscr-a-function-in-c). And just google it. :-) Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't take 3 parameters, it takes 4:

```
int mMenu(int& choice, char& sure, bool& quit, char& ctrl,)
            // << the "," in the end 
            // shouldn't be there
```

How to fix it? Add the missing parameter:

```
mMenu (choice, sure, quit, ctrl/*<a ctrl parameter goes here>*/);
```

You even defined the variable `ctrl`, just forgot to pass it as the last argument:-)

Comment: OMG! I'm such an idiot XD I guess that was THE most noobiest question you have ever answered! Thank you so much :L

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have defined mMenu as taking four arguments but call it only with three

```
mMenu (choice, sure, quit);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that mMenu does not take 3 arguments. It takes 4.

There are two ways to make this compile:

- Change mMenu so that it takes 3 arguments.
- Call mMenu with its current 4 arguments.