# Why is the error "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" showing when I run my c code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

How to fix the error `"collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"`, please do not downvote this because it is too trivial I have just started to learn my first language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int value()
{
        printf("Twinkle Twinkle little star");

        printf("How I wonder what you are");

        printf("Up above the sky so high");

        printf("Like a diamong in the sky!");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is always recommended to include code as text instead of linking images. If you will be downvoted this could be the reason. ;)

Comment: Possibly dupe of [this thread of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272525/what-does-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status-mean).

Answer (score 0):

The `collect2.exe: ld returned 1 exit status` error is a consequence of an error that came before it. Not sure if this'll help, but try re-naming `int value()` to `int main()`.

Answer (score 0):

`ld` is a linker whose purpose is to link multiple object files. In your code, you used `#include <stdio.h>` which is a header file containing IO operations. So the linker at this point will combine that header file with the object file created from your source code. But linker needs to have an entry point in your source code relative to which it can link all object files. That entry point in C is provided by using `main()` function. As @TDO mentioned, replace `value()` with `main()`.

Edit: If you are unsure about any of the above terminology, I would advise to use search engine to read more about them.