# How do I fix undefined reference to `fsm' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status?

Tags: c, generics

I have started to learn C recently.
I don't know what's wrong with my code. I keep getting:

```
undefined reference to 'fsm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you please help to fix it?

**1) This is my fsm_main.c file.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cstack.h"
#include "fsm.h"

int main(){
    char string_input[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(string_input);
    printf("string : %s\n",string_input);
    if (fsm(string_input))
      printf("All matched correctly\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**2) Boolean.h file**

```
#ifndef BOOLEAN_H
#define BOOLEAN_H

typedef int boolean;

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#endif
```

**3) cstack.h file**

```
#ifndef CSTACK_H
#define CSTACK_H
#include "boolean.h"

typedef struct cstacknode{
    char data;
    struct cstacknode *next;
}*cstack;

void init_cstack(cstack *);
void cpush(cstack*,char);
char cpop(cstack *);
boolean is_cfull(void);
boolean is_cempty(cstack);
void print_cstack(cstack);

#endif
```

**4) cstack.c file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "boolean.h"
#include "cstack.h"

void init_cstack(cstack *s){
    (*s) = NULL;
}

void cpush(cstack*s, char x){
    cstack  temp;
    temp= (cstack)malloc(sizeof(struct cstacknode));
    temp -> data = x;
    temp -> next = (*s);
    (*s) = temp;
}

char cpop(cstack *s){
    cstack temp;
    char data_popped;
    temp = *s;
    data_popped =temp->data;
    *s =temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return data_popped;
}

void print_cstack( cstack s){
    if(!is_cempty(s)){
        printf("%d\n", s->data);
        print_cstack(s->next);
   }
}

boolean is_cfull(void){
    cstack temp;
    temp = (cstack) malloc (sizeof(struct cstacknode));
    if(temp == NULL)
        return TRUE;
    else {
        free(temp);
        return FALSE;
    }
}

boolean is_cempty( cstack s){
    if (s == NULL)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
   
}
```

**5) fsm.h file**

```
#ifndef FSM_H
#define FSM_H

#include "boolean.h"

boolean fsm(char *);
boolean is_open(char);
boolean is_close(char);
boolean is_brother(char,char);

#endif
```

**6) fsm.c file**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fsm.h"
#include "cstack.h"

boolean is_open(char c) {
   return ((c == '{') || (c == '[') || (c == '{'));
}

boolean is_close(char c) {
   return ((c == '}') || (c == ']') || (c == '}'));
}

boolean is_brother(char op, char cl) {
   return (((op == '{') && (cl == '}')) || ((op == '[') && (cl == ']')) || ((op == '{') && (cl == '}')));
}

boolean fsm(char my_input[]) {
   int i = 1;
   int nextstate = 0;
   cstack top;
   char o, c;

   init_cstack( & top);
   while (1) {
      switch (nextstate) {
      case 0:
         i++;
         if (is_open(my_input[i]))
            nextstate = 1;
         else if (is_close(my_input[i]))
            nextstate = 2;
         else if (my_input[i] == '0')
            nextstate = 3;
         else 
            nextstate = 4;
         break;

      case 1:
         if (!is_cfull()) {
            cpush( & top, my_input[i]);
            nextstate = 0;
         } else {
            printf("Error! stack is full\n");
            exit(0);
         }
         break;
      case 2:
         if (!is_cempty(top)) {
            if (is_brother(cpop( & top), my_input[i])) {
               nextstate = 0;

            } else {
              // printf("Error! open and close delimiter do not match\n");
              printf("Error!  open and close  delimiters do not match\n");
               return FALSE;
            }
         } else {
            printf("Error! No open delimiter to compare to\n");
            return FALSE;
         }
         break;

      case 3:
         if (is_cempty(top)) {
            return TRUE;
         } 
         else {
            printf("Error! stack is full\n");
            return FALSE;
         }
         break;

      case 4:
         nextstate = 0;

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you linking your code? Do you list `fsm.o` (or `fsm.c`) as one of the files?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For SO to work it isimportantthat you respond to comments. For that purpose you should monitor your question after posting it. Without you adding the missing information your problem cannot be answered and your question will not be useful for any further vistor of the size.

Comment: See [What does `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272525/what-does-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status-mean)

Comment: I am linking my code with fsm.o , fsm_main.o and cstack.o