# Visual Studio C++, Identifier not found

Tags: c++

This is my code!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
int no;
cout<<"Enter a number";
cin>>no;
getch();
}
```

and I get this error here!

[image: This is the error I get]

I think I might have to download some extra visual studio c++ related directories, but still some suggestions please

Comment: Try `std::cin`, `std::cout`, and so on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930138/is-clrscr-a-function-in-c

Comment: So many bad things.  I suggest you get yourself a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to see how C++ should be coded.

Comment: This code is like a collection of worst practices. Please learn C++ from a better source.

Comment: [Somebody's been teaching you Turbo C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/930141/560648). This question is a perfect example of how that information will not serve you very well in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

`clrscr()` is not a standard function.  Visual Studio does not have it.  However, MSDN does document how to [clear the screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022.aspx) using `system("cls")`, or `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()` and `FillConsoleOutputAttribute()`.

As for the `cin`/`cout` errors, you need to prefix them with the `std::` namespace qualifier, eg `std::cin` and `std::cout`, or use a separate `using namespace std;` statement in your code below the header `#include` statements.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

void clrscr()
{
    std::system("cls");
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int no;
    std::cout << "Enter a number";
    std::cin >> no;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void clrscr()
{
    std::system("cls");
}

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    int no;
    cout << "Enter a number";
    cin >> no;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your c++ program doesn't know what clrscr(); is..

you have to define that function. To define it, see @Remy Lebeau's answer.

One quick solution instead of creating a function to clear out the screen is to simply cout a bunch of blank spaces.

so in your main you can simply put :

```
std::cout << string(50, '\n');
```